# Verifying JWT signed with the RS256 algorithm using public key in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a sample code to validate the JWT returned by a provider. I have to validate the token against a Public Key which is stored in a different server. Any idea if the below code is good to do the validation?

Code:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/publickey", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getkey() {

    String token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJtMEptdUpmNnVreV9IT0ZMZnAzY1lJN2xMay1nX1JBVmJzZHRYaW9sQzFjIn0.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.gXpkpmdB1BsWnCGUsWsOfcp_dBsW_4zAwrCX2hOdJ_GKodPooi5-8ySUuH7OXDltUfmjhstu2fPQrl3fjug-7YAUAs6o7Boih25fItrTX3-DINkBjyWgIux-1TNoJKh_IPFc4CSIKEGwo3B40BR-wtefx5j44nq6-69JQmqdRDN45AS0NYUc72drk3iHB-msktWlgFsgh9sC0buzvEYppYfWKChgRUbIxpcMLGNnlMIRMiAhJ-G2Kt6cIA0sA3aPLjPueyaZ8wsmXCMpblsPkOuZu92PxtmX5WOO26ZJ91r_VLpHwPQk0r091dh_tgW9cZ4WVPqIEWEa_D_oKGdiqg";

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> tokenResponse = rs.exchange(GET_TOKEN_URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);


    DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
    JwkProvider provider = new UrlJwkProvider(GET_TOKEN_URL);
    Jwk jwk;
    try {
        jwk = provider.get(jwt.getKeyId());
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);
        algorithm.verify(jwt);

        // Check expiration
        if (jwt.getExpiresAt().before(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exired token!");
        }

    } catch (JwkException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Exception:

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://<>/open/<>/certs/.well-known/jwks.json

Comment: Why not just use spring security to avoid all this additional complexity? Given the usecase it should only require pointing to the jwks URL and a few properties

Comment: Any idea if i can find a documentation around it. I have been playing around with Spring Security and i do not want to do authorization on the Role.

Is there a method i can use from the io.jsonwebtoken?

Comment: Their documentation is the best start, there is also samples ont eh Spring Security github repo. 

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/

Specifically you'll want to look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver